# Nth day of month in a xts object

Tags: r, date, xts

prices is an xts object

```
period.ends = endpoints(prices, 'months',k=1)
```

with this line i find position of the last day of the month in a time series.

How to find position of the first day of month (not always 1 of the month)? And the second day?

Thank you

Comment: Does the answer here help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13005907/1270695

Comment: The solution there was: x[.indexmday(x) == 1].  The problem is that this function use calendar day while i want the first day of month whatever calendar day it is

Comment: You didn't look at the "update" in the answer that I had linked directly to, I guess....

Comment: ok, sorry. lapply(split(prices, "months"), function(x) x[1]): with this i extract the first day of month (all the row of data). But my objective is to determine the position of all the first day of month in my original xts time series

Answer (score 2):

```
startpoints <- function (x, on = "months", k = 1) {
  head(endpoints(x, on, k) + 1, -1)
}

period.starts = startpoints(prices, 'months', k=1)
```

See also: `xts:::startof` and `xts::firstof`